# How to send signal once per 3 seconds using ReactiveCocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I want to send signal only once per 3 seconds (so if there is another signal again, skip it if previous didn't end still) 
There is my code :

```
 RACSignal *textViewSignal = [self.textView.rac_textSignal throttle:3];
    [textViewSignal subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        [[BKSocketManager sharedManager] sendTypingRequestForChatroomId:_chatRoom.chatRoomId
                                                                success:^(Response *response) {
                                                                    NSLog(@"Typing request success");
                                                                }
                                                                failure:^(NSError *error) {
                                                                    NSLog(@"Typing request failed with error: %@", error);
                                                                }
                                                                    tag:0];
    }];
```

But it just send last signal if delay between them more 3 seconds.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Is the issue that ongoing requests to the socket manager are not cancelled if there is new one?

Comment: In this piece of code, i will send only latest signal with 3 second non-sending this signal again(If i type again and again, it throttle every signal and send signal only after 3 seconds i end typing). I want to send signal when u start typing and send it again if u keep typing, but not on every signal, only after 3 seconds between them. If u stop typing - no signals. Is that clear enough for you?)

Answer (score 1):

`throttle` will delay the sending of a value by the argument's time value, and not send it at all if a new value comes and replaces it before then.

If you are looking to send a value every 3 seconds, you should use

`+ (RACSignal *)interval:(NSTimeInterval)interval onScheduler:(RACScheduler *)scheduler;`

to set up a signal that sends a (unimportant) value every 3 seconds. Then, use

`- (RACSignal *)sample:(RACSignal *)sampler;`

to send the latest value from your source signal when the `interval` signal sends a value.

This would look something like

```
 RACSignal* timer = [RACSignal interval:3 onScheduler:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler];    
 RACSignal *textViewSignal = [[self.textView.rac_textSignal sample:timer] distinctUntilChanged];

 [textViewSignal subscribeNext:^(id x) {
     [[BKSocketManager sharedManager] sendTypingRequestForChatroomId:_chatRoom.chatRoomId
                                                             success:^(Response *response) {
                                                                    NSLog(@"Typing request success");
                                                                }
                                                             failure:^(NSError *error) {
                                                                    NSLog(@"Typing request failed with error: %@", error);
                                                                }
                                                                 tag:0];
    }];
```

The `distinctUntilChanged` call at the end will prevent you from kicking off network requests when nothing has changed as it guarantees that it will never send two consecutive values that are equal to each other.

Comment: Almost what i wanted. I have only a little problem there. If i type in interval between 3 and 0 seconds and then stop typing, i will get next signal, but i don't want to. I mean 3(typing request send) ---- 2----trying to type----1----0(get new signal because i tried to type), but i want to ignore any signal from textview in this 3seconds.

Comment: This is what the `sample` method does. It sends the latest value from the source signal (`rac_textSignal`) only when the timer sends a signal. So you will get a value every 3 seconds exactly, and none in-between.

Comment: But seem's it doesn't, i checked this and it works as i said in comment ( its send signal for last in-between signal at end )

Comment: You want to stop receiving `next`s during the 3 second window, and only receive a `next` if a change occurs after that window?

Comment: Seem's right. There always must be an 3 or more seconds window between typing requests.

Comment: This is what `throttle` is designed to do. Throttle guarantees that there will never be less than 3 seconds between consecutive `next`s. To be honest, I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve. If it's to keep from inundating your server with requests, `throttle` is what you need. If you want to send requests every 3 seconds, `interval` is what you need.

Comment: Throttle isn't what we need, because it will prevent sending next (throttle:3.0) not only 3 seconds. If i will type 2 minutes, it will send next after 123 seconds from begin(3 seconds after i stop typing). But as i said, we want to send signal 'not more than every 3 seconds'. That solution you described in answer almost what we want.